# how can i click another page's link which includes functions in current page

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is 2 pages. main.jsp and list.jsp

when I execute goPage() in main.jsp I would like to make event of click  list.jsp's nav>ul>li(2).

because list.jsp shows information by click of javascript function
so i need to make click when i enter list.jsp

so anyway would be great if i can show elements in list.jsp

this is main.jsp

```
<body>
<div class="main_wrap">
    <div class="sub1"><div class="main_title1"><a href="javascript:goPage();" onclick="callChart(50035); callPie(50035); callMap(50035); callTitle('살인');">월별 통계</a></div></div>
    <div class="sub2"><div class="main_title2"><a href="javascript:goPage();" onclick="callChart(50035); callPie(50035); callMap(50035); callTitle('살인');">발생 현황</div></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function goPage() {
    location.href="list.jsp";

}
</script>
</body>
```

this is list.jsp
all function is located in each scrript file.

```
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="title">발생현황</div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="main.jsp"><img src="css/f4f0edb08c97567ce6b0475a63bf7000.png" alt="Italian Trulli" width="50px" height="30px"></img></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callChart(50035); callPie(50035); callMap(50035); callTitle('살인');">살인</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callChart(50047); callPie(50047); callMap(50047); callTitle('절도');">절도</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callChart(50033); callPie(50033); callMap(50033); callTitle('강간');">강간</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callChart(50039); callPie(50039); callMap(50039); callTitle('강도');">강도</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="chart_map">
        <span class="div_sub1">지도 전국 범죄율</span>
        <div class='korea'></div>
    </div>

    <div class="chart_pie">
        <span class="div_sub1">검거자</span>
        <div class="pie_arrests"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/pie_period.js?v=<%=System.currentTimeMillis() %>"></script>
    <script src="js/pie_arrests.js?v=<%=System.currentTimeMillis() %>"></script>
    <script src="js/korea_map.js?v=<%=System.currentTimeMillis() %>"></script>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to make a click when going to `list.jsp`, maybe try running the same code when loading `list.jsp` instead, so add something like this to the file:

```
<!-- list.jsp -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    callChart(50035);
    callPie(50035);
    callMap(50035);
    callTitle('살인');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could something like:

1. Redirect to the list.jsp with a query string
2. If there is a query string with a certain key - click the button

Code sample
On main page:

```
function goPage() {
    location.href="list.jsp?doclick=1";
}
```

On list page:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoader', function () {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const myParam = urlParams.get('doclick');
    if(myParam == 1) {
      callChart(50033); 
      callPie(50033); 
      callMap(50033); 
      callTitle('강간');
    }
});
```